# Java sqlite - Delete rows where rowid < value

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite database with, lets say 333 rows. I have a value that is 300 as an integer called "value". I want to delete every row in the database with an rowid less than "value". So far I have this:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM wifi_probe_requests WHERE rowid < " + value;
```

But so far It doesn't work. There is no error or output from it, so the command works, but it doesn't work as I want it to. So I guess the command is invalid and I need to change it to something else.

I also tried:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM wifi_probe_requests WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM wifi_probe_requests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT " + value + ",1)";
```

But that takes the value of the "id" cell and not the rowid.

Help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM wifi_probe_requests WHERE rowid < " + value;
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: This could be caused by a number of things.  Top of the list includes your not committing the transaction, and your not running the actual query you described to us.  Please include the relevant code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added the exec code...

Comment: When you run a select with the same `WHERE` condition do you get any records back?

Comment: Although you might have 333 records in the table, do any of them actually have a ID value less than 300? Run query as suggested by @TimBiegeleisen to see if you have any, or just run query without `WHERE` clause, to see what records you actually have in the table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Running: sql = "SELECT * FROM wifi_probe_requests WHERE rowid < " + value; Doesn't give any output when I go through it. There ARE records in it, I put them there. I get those by using: sql = "SELECT * FROM wifi_probe_requests LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wifi_probe_requests) OFFSET " + value;

Comment: @Andreas As far as I can see, the rowid is the actual row number and not a value in a cell called rowid in the row. I want the actual row number and as far as I can see rowid can be used.

Comment: The [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) is not the actual row number but a value in a cell.

Comment: @CL. Thanks, kinda figured that out.